# Running Rsync in the background

Tags: rsync, nohup

Trying to run rsync in the background

```
rsync -rt /home/2/folder/1234 root@12345678:/stor/folder
```

<kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd>

Entering bg

and it runs in the background but now when I exit my SSH connection it stops?

I tried `nohup rsync -rt /home/2/folder/1234 root@12345678:/stor/folder &`
but it doesn't ask for the password so it doesn't work?

And is there any other way to move files faster with rsync it seems pretty slow with the current command I'm using?

Comment: look into tmux and/or screen for detach abilities. Try another cipher if compute power is your limitation.

Comment: Running `rsync` with the `-z` option will compress transfers to use less bandwidth = most likely faster.

Comment: Also, if you have a regular backup task, look into writing a script and execute with `cron`. This is a most steady way to have tasks executed in the background.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that processes that you start over an ssh connection - and the same goes for a local terminal instance - stop when the ssh connection - or the terminal console or window - is closed. To allow processes to continue while you are not anymore connected, you can use multiplexer tools like **GNU screen** or **tmux**. These tools allow to "detach" a session from the terminal. The session then keeps running on the host system. You later can reconnect to such session to interact with it again.